# What's the down method for foreignIdFor()?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-9, laravel-migrations

If I run this in my migration up method, what do I put in the down method?

```php
$table->foreignIdFor(MyClass::class)->nullable()->constrained();
```

Thanks!

Comment: The down method should contain whatever is needed to undo whatever the up method did.

Answer (score 1):

In the down method you should drop the foreign key:

```
$table->dropForeign(['column_name']);
$table->dropColumn(['column_name']);
```

Comment: Thanks! And what about the index and the actual column? I need 3 different actions?

Comment: You are right, the column should also be dropped. Edited my answer. You actually need only two actions - first to drop the foreign index, and then to drop the column itself.